# How can I make iWork load my plugin? (Like MathType?)

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, iwork

I would like to create a plugin for iWork, like MathType. The issue is that the plugin architecture for iWork is entirely undocumented. I have experience creating plugins for other applications, such as Xcode. To make a plugin for Xcode, you need to make sure your plugin bundle is located in the proper directory where Xcode looks for plugins when it launches, and that your Info.plist is set up properly.

I have no idea how MathType is able to embed itself in the iWork apps. I've gone over all of its install logs and grepped over my entire machine to find all the files it installs - all of them are placed inside my Applications directory in a file called "MathType 6". Nothing about its Info.plist appears magical in anyway.

There's also the LinkBack plugin which embeds itself in the iWork apps. I've attempted to contact the authors of both MathType and LinkBack a few times over the past year, but they've never gotten back to me.

Is there anyone who knows how to write a plugin for an iWork application? What are the magical essentials that I need for iWork applications to load my plugins when they start up?

Comment: MathType doesn't embed itself in iWork as you found out from the installer — rather, the opposite is occurring: iWork works with MathType.

Comment: @grgarside - You're telling me that the iWork applications are hardcoded to look for an installed copy of MathType, then? What criteria do they use - how can I setup my own application such that when I open Pages, Keynote, or Numbers and check the "Insert" menu, it includes the option to insert content using my plugin?

Comment: Yeah, precisely (along with EndNote Citations). I don't know exactly how it's achieved though.

Comment: @grgarside - I find it disturbing and hard to believe that Apple would give such a half-baked product a monopoly like this. Maybe I can look into adding stuff to the Services menu instead and pursue tying my own app into it that way...